# JavaScript start iterating Map() from specific element/index

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, iteration

I know that elements in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can be iterated over, in the order of insertion.

Let's assume we have this map:

```
const a = new Map();
a.set('x', 5);
a.set('y', 10);
a.set('z', 5);
```

And we want to find first element in `a` with the value `5` and then the next element with same value of `5`.

```
// el will be 5, 10, 5...
for(const el of a) {
  if(el === 0) {
    // How can I iteratate over `a` starting from index(el) + 1
    for (??) {}
  }    
}
```

If I was using an `Array` instead we could do something like (ignoring the keys):

```
const a = new Array(5, 10, 5);
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  if(a[i] === 5) {
    // Here I can start iterating from i + 1
    for(let j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
         a[j] === 5 && console.log('FOUND!');
    }
  }
}
```

I am not very familiar with `iterators`, but I think it should be somehow possible to start iterating from a specific element in the map.

```
const x = a.get('x');
 // iterate over Map `a` starting from the element that comes after x
```

One solution, that I am not particularly happy about, is to get a copy of the keys or entries each time we perform the operation `const elements = a.entries()`, so then we could quickly iterate over it, but it uses a lot of extra memory.

Comment: do you have a practical use case? just curious.

Comment: It's for grouping together some elements. I go over a list, and based on the current element I have to find one or more elements that appear after the current one and meet some criteria. I could use an `Array`, but elements can be added/removed, so I would still need a way to quickly know the position of each element (thus Map suits well as I can directly access the element based on its `id`/`key`).

Comment: maps are not really made for iterating. it has an implemented [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), but it does not allows to fork the iteration.

Comment: Some other use case would be, find element `x` in the `Map` and delete all elements that were added at a later point (without having to iterate through the map to find `x`).

Comment: i would take an array, maybe in combination with a map for the index.

Comment: I know there are other ways to go around this, but almost all of them use extra memory or add complexity to the code. I was hoping there is an way to avoid that. By continuing to iterate from a specific point.

Comment: How about iterating over an array of the keys? `const keysArray = [...a.keys()]` ... and `.get` the value for performing your comparison logic.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi I mentioned that in the last sentence of my question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generators to do this,..

One advantage is that you can short circuit generators with a break..

Example below..

```js
const a = new Map();
a.set('x', 5);
a.set('y', 10);
a.set('z', 5);

a.set('a', 10);
a.set('b', 5);

function* findFirstThenNext(m, v) {
  let ix = 0; 
  for (const mm of m) {
    if (v === mm[1]) {
      yield {ix, key:mm[0]};
    }
    ix += 1;
  }
}

let count = 0;
for (const ret of findFirstThenNext(a, 5)) {
  console.log(`Found @${ret.ix} with key ${ret.key}`);
  count ++;
  if (count >= 2) break;
}
```

Using a mix of the for loop and iterators, you could create simple list, then do your double for loops using iterators.

The nice thing here, is if you use this sort of for looping in lots of places, then the `makeOuterInnerIter` function can be re-used for any iterable.

```js
const a = new Map();
a.set('x', 5);
a.set('y', 10);
a.set('z', 5);

function* makeOuterInnerIter(iter) {
  const stack = Array.from(iter);
  for (let ol = 0; ol < stack.length; ol += 1) {
    yield {
      value: stack[ol],
      inner: (function *inner() {
        for (let il = ol + 1; il < stack.length; il += 1) yield stack[il];
      })()
    };
  }
}


for (const {value: [okey, ovalue], inner} of makeOuterInnerIter(a)) {
  console.log(`outer: ${okey}: ${ovalue}`);
  for (const [ikey, ivalue] of inner) {
    console.log(`  inner: ${ikey}: ${ivalue}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't necessarily need the reference `f`, you can just `for (const ret of findFirstThenNext(a, 5))` and it would work the same way.

Comment: But will this work if I then want to continue the outer loop and do the same for second element (find all other occurrences that appear after it)? In the end I would want to have the same functionality as the one in the example with two nested loops, where `i` goes from `0` to `N` and `j` goes from `i+1` to `N`. Because if we wrap the `for ret of findFirstThenNext(a, el)` loop into another loop, `for el of a`, there is no way for the inner loop to start searching for elements that only appear after `el`, right?

Comment: @Cristy  I've done a second snippet that think does what your wanting..

Comment: But that will allocate a new `Array` each time this operation is done, so it's exactly the same as getting directly `a.entries()`. And if we get the entries then we can simply iterate over them and not use any iterators at all. My question is how to continue iterating from a specific element in the `Map` without allocating a `new Array`.

Comment: @Cristy  It only allocates the array once.   I assuming you was wanting to do this  to avoid `for (let i = x; i <y; i += 1)`  double for loop using iterators to keep things cleaner.   Generators go from a to b, there is no restart options unfortunately..

Comment: The question is not about clean code, but performant code. Ok, so it looks like it is a limitation of the current implementation of Map, using generators, which does not allow to start at a specific point in the iteration, but only at first element ("index" 0).

Comment: @Cristy  Wasn't aware it was about performant code, you didn't mention that in your question.  You did mention `uses a lot of extra memory.`.  If this is an issue, and your keys & values can be big, one idea is to store your `keys` and `values` as objects,  `a.set({k: "theBigKey"}, {v: "a massive value"})`,  This would make `Object.entries` take very little extra memory as they are both references.  Maybe a nice feature of generators would be a sort of bookmark feature to be able to start a new generator from that point.

Comment: @Keith Well, the issue with using more memory in JavaScript is almost never because you run out of memory but because code execution gets slower and because of all that GC that will happen when that memory will be dealocated. They keys are strings, which I assume are interned anyway by the JS engine. If I were to use `Objects` as keys I would have to create a new Object whenever I want to access a specific key, which would create even more garbage, or implement some object pooling for that which would add too much complexity for this use case.

Comment: To be more clear, I am not really looking for alternative solutions, I just wanted to know if it's possible to start/continue iterating a `Map` from a specific element, the same way you can do using pointers in a language like C.

Comment: No, Javascript maps, don't expose it's Linked List or whatever it using internally for iterating.  You could of course mix a Javascript Map's with a Linked List to give you the same features.  But your not looking for an alternative so that's of no use.  So basically I'd say the answer to your question is, no you can't.  Unless in the future maybe ES spec puts in features to expose it's internal iterator with maybe some boookmarking / next / prev features..

Comment: @Cristy   Oh, just a thought.. `language like C`   Have you ever considered using WebAssembly?   If your comfortable using C, and you find Javascript's Maps lacking, you could compile C/C++ map lib's and use them instead.

Comment: I want something that would both result in a clean code and be performant, going for WebAssembly will be an overkill in my case. As I see that there is no way to iterate from a specific element I think the best solution for my case is to just get the list of `keys` and iterate over that instead of iterating over the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with generators:

```
function* itWrapper(iterator, value) {
    let found = false;
    for(let item of iterator) {
        if(item[1] == value) {
            if(found) {
                yield 'FOUND!'; // or: yield item[1];
            } else {
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use like this:

```
for(let item of itWrapper(a[Symbol.iterator](), 5)) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Since `a` is already an iterable in that example, it suffices to just `for(let item of itWrapper(a, 5))`

Comment: This is a cool solution, but it doesn't work in my case. I might have to search for "next 5 items that have the same value", not necessarily second occurrence. The example with having to find only next identical value was just that, an example.